# Not able to programmatically scroll the page in PhantomJS, fully inside page.evaluate()

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I want to be able to scroll the page to the end, basically to load more content. For this i am using following:

```
page.evaluate(function(){
  // Scrolls to the bottom of page
  window.document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;
})
var count = page.content.match(/(class=\".*?row.*?page.*?\".*?\<\/div\>)/g);
```

This has worked if i do it in this way, basically set the scrollTop in page.evaluate, and get out and check for loaded content using: `page.content.match()`

But I need to interact with the page some more, so I want to do this completely inside `page.evaluate()`. For that I am doing this:

```
page.evaluate(function(){
  // Scrolls to the bottom of page
  window.document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;

  delay = 5000
  // synchonously wait for 5 sec
  if (delay){
    var curr = new Date().getTime();
    delay += curr;
    while (curr < delay){
        curr = new Date().getTime();
    }
  }
  var count = $(selector).length;
})
```

I am facing problems in this, the content is not getting loaded. saw the page with page.render, but still no solution. I can see the scrollTop property getting set using on page console messages using this:

```
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg){
    console.log("PAGE> ",msg);
};
```

Here is the test URL I am working with:
http://www.flipkart.com/all/disney~brand/pr?sid=all

Comment: See the comments [here](http://www.phpied.com/sleep-in-javascript/), this sleep is a really bad idea. Because it's blocking, your fetch more data function will probably not be triggered. Does this actually work for you? You need `setTimeout` outside of `evaluate` and then call `evaluate` with your additional code. It is not bad for performance to have multiple `evaluate` calls.

Comment: yes, I ended up doing that, as i was not able to make it work within `page.evaluate()`. Isn't `sleep()`s  supposed to be blocking. The idea here is to trigger the scroll event and wait for few seconds for content to get loaded.

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to be blocking, but since javascript is single-threaded none of your intended events that you want to wait for are actually triggered.

Comment: So when i trigger an event in `evaluate` and come out, and wait for few seconds, is it working because page's js is sandboxed and is separate from phantomjs's js flow?
Also, if that is the case with event triggering itself getting blocked, because of sleep, then what is the way to trigger an event and wait for sometime to check the effects of the event trigger. should i set a listener for some mutation event for loaded content?

Comment: If the event is in the page context you could register a listener which then sets a variable that you can repeatedly check from the outside. I didn't run any experiments how your type of sleep performs regarding the halting of js execution in the page context.